# If statement in function doesn´t return desired result

Tags: python-3.x

I want this function to check if there is " " in list test_board.
But everytime it returns that what is after else statement.
Why does it ?

```py
test_board = ['#','X','O','X ','O',' ','O','X','O','X']

def full_board_check(board):
    for thing in board:
        if thing == " ":
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

When I call the funcition it returns True every time. No matter if there is 
" " in list or not. I want it to outuput False if any of the elements in the list is equal to " " which would mean that board isn´t full. And if there is no " " in the list it should return True because the board is full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to see the error in your logic is this:

```
def full_board_check(board):
    for thing in board:
        if thing == " ":
            return False
        else:
            # do nothing
            pass
    return True
```

The problem with your code is that when the first element is checked, you are returning `True` immediately. Not going through the whole list.

If you want a more pythonic way of doing what you are trying to, just do:

```
def full_board_check(board):
   return ' ' not in board
```